# Three Ways of Balancing the Last Page Don't Work in Acmart Class

Tags: two-column, acmart

I want to balance the last page of a two columned article using the acmart class with the sigconf option (`\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`).

What I have tried:

- (1) using `\balance` in the first column of the last page
- (2) using `\usepackage{flushend}`
- (3) trying to use `\usepackage{multicol}`

What the outcomes are:

- (1) The References (that start on the first column of the last page) get pushed under the page in the first column, like so:
  [image: Trying balance command]
- (2) Nothing
- (3) The two columns get divided into 4 columns using `\begin{multicols}{2}`

Has anybody encountered these issues and found a solution ? As a sidenote: I am working in Overleaf

Answer (score 1):

In the case of acmart.class, I cannot use \usepackage{balance} and \usepackage{flushend} li in the same manner as you.

I discovered the following workaround for the acmart.cls file.
The following statement manages the acmart.cls file.

#### Step 1/2

```
\usepackage{multicol}
```

#### Step 2/2

```
\onecolumn \begin{multicols}{2}

\bibliographystyle{abbrev} 
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{multicols}
```

Comment: You saved my day, I was getting crazy with this requirement from Sheridan Communications asking me to use `\balance`